# Selecting certain values in dataset and changing their values

Tags: sparklyr, dplyr

I have the tbl format dataset for my project and I have one column where I have mixed values (although I can differentiate which are which) and I want to change the selected values of that column by dividing them by certain number, what is my best approach for this?
I have thought of writing mutate and somehow applying if statements inside but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

By leveraging the dplyr package, you can do

```
mutate_if(condition_to_check, funs(. / number_to_divide_by))
```